# How does an offline Root CA sign OCSP Response?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority, ocsp

As Root CA are kept offline for security purposes, how does it sign OCSP Response sent by Client for Intermediate Certificate Status Check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OCSP responses may be signed not only by the CA itself, but also a designated OCSP signer. That's an X.509 certificate issued by that CA with the `OCSPSigning` ([`1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.9`](http://oid-info.com/get/1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.9)) extended key usage.

For details see [RFC 6960, section 4.2.2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6960#section-4.2.2.2).